# Is there an official name for the pasta in between carbonara and cacio e pepe?

Tags: pasta, italian-cuisine, traditional

Traditionally, the four pastas of Rome are *carbonara, cacio e pepe, alla gricia*, and *amatriciana*.

You get *alla gricia* from a *cacio e pepe* by adding guanciale (pork jowl), and adding egg on top of that gives you *carbonara*.

My question is: if you were to make pasta involving cheese, pepper, eggs and pasta water, but **no guanciale**, what would that pasta be called? Is there a "proper" name for it? Or would you just say "carbonara without guanciale/cacio e pepe with eggs"?

Comment: We actually make this occasionally in my family and call it "pasta non carborundum", which is a weird mock-Latin joke.  Nobody else calls it that, though.  It's pretty good, but add some chopped sun-dried tomatoes for texture/flavor contrast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a quick google search, it seems to be named "cacio e uova", uova in Italian means eggs.

If you can read italian this giallo zafferano recipe might help
https://ricette.giallozafferano.it/Pasta-cacio-e-ova.html

Here in Italy some people including my family put cream instead of eggs so if you were to give it a name it would probably be called "cacio e crema" but personally I would just stick to the conventional recipes.